# Restrict new events (select) to background events only

Tags: fullcalendar

Basically I have a calendar with background events in various areas. I want to restrict users to ONLY create events that are within the range of a background event.

This is an example of the calendar:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey4ou.png

Only green highlighted areas should allow new events to be selected over them.

This is the full code for my calendar:

```
 if ($('#calendar').is(':visible')) { //if the container is visible on the page
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        height: 'auto',
        allDaySlot: false,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: false,
        weekends: false,
        selectable: true,
        minTime: "10:00",
        maxTime: "21:00",
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var csrfToken = $('input[name="csrfToken"]').attr('value');
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Csrf-Token', csrfToken);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/availableSlots/' + '@UserController.getCurrentUser.getUid',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    var events = [];
                    $(response).each(function () {
                        var event = {
                            id: $(this).attr('availabilityId'),
                            title: "One-Time",
                            start: $(this).attr('startDate'),
                            end: $(this).attr('endDate'),
                            dow: [],
                            rendering: 'background'
                        };
                        if ($(this).attr("weekly") === true) {
                            event.title = "Weekly";
                            event.dow = [moment($(this).attr('startDate')).isoWeekday()];
                            event.start = moment($(this).attr('startDate')).format("HH:mm");
                            event.end = moment($(this).attr('endDate')).format("HH:mm");
                        }
                        events.push(event);
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            })
        },
        eventRender: function (event, eventElement) {
            eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<button onclick='removeAppointment(\"" + event + "\")' class='no-button eventDelete'><i class=\"material-icons md-18\">close</i></button>");
        },
        select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
            if(($("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', [1])).length > 0) {
                $.alert({
                    title: "Hold on there",
                    content: "You already have an appointment slot selected, cancel the current one to change your time.",
                    buttons: {
                        ok: {
                            text: "Okay"
                        }
                    }
                })
            } else {
            var newAppointment = {
                title : "Appointment",
                id: 1,
                userId: '@UserController.getCurrentUser.getUid',
                start: moment(start).format(),
                end: moment(end).format(),
                weekly: false
            };
            $.confirm({
                title: 'Confirm Appointment',
                content: 'Do you want to create an appointment for this time?',
                theme: 'modern',
                buttons: {
                    yes: {
                        text: 'Yes, Create',
                        btnClass: 'btn-primary',
                        keys: ['enter', 'shift'],
                        action: function () {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newAppointment, true);
                        }
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        text: 'No, Cancel.'
                    }
                }
            });
            }
        },
        selectOverlap: function(event) {
            return event.rendering === 'background';
        }
    });
} else {
    setTimeout(createMakeAppointmentCalendar, 50); //wait 50 ms, then try again
}
}
```

Code's still in dev so it may not be the most optimized / clean, but I basically need to restrict new event creation to only backround events.

Any idea / tips? I haven't been able to find a similar use case.

Comment: I can see 2 options: 1) In the select method, check whether the proposed time is completely within any existing background events. For this you'd have to fetch the list of current events and loop through them, comparing each one. 2) Alternatively, switch your logic round to a more conventional approach. Use events (or background events) - together with businessHours if necessary - to indicate the areas which are _not_ available (after all I assume these are slots already taken by something else). Then you can use the "selectOverlap" option straightforwardly to limit what's possible.